# How to color specific columns in a dataframe using Python multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm having trouble coloring cells using pandas.
I have this dataframe that contains a pivot table with an aggregate of orders and in which step are.

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Date': ['2021-10-01', '2021-10-02', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-04','2021-10-05','2021-10-06','2021-10-07','2021-10-08'],
        'Waiting_for': [5, 0, 0, 10,34,10,4,12],
        'Picking': [20,12,5,9,0,21, 19, 18],
        'Shipped': [20, 21,7,9,12, 19,0, 18],
        'Received': [5,7,10,9,20,6,10,5]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  
# Print the output.  
print(df)
```

And I'd like to highlight cells following all these conditions:

- The aggregate is greater than 0
- Depending on which step are they, for example I want to highlight all orders are in **waiting for more than 32 days**, orders that are in **picking for more than 34 days**, orders that are in **Shipped for more than 36 days**.

I'm trying to write a function and then use *df.style.apply*, but I'm not get used to python and it's difficult for me.

```
def highlight_col(x):
    #copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df1 = x.copy()
    #set by condition
    mask = df1['Date'] < (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=35))
    df1.loc[mask, :] = 'background-color: grey'
    df1.loc[~mask,:] = 'background-color: ""'
    return df1  

df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
```

The desired output:

[image: output]

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. You have numbers in the columns, but you seem to be referencing date bounds. Like waiting for more than 33 days etc. I don't understand. What is the number 5 under waiting for and how does it relate to the amount of time it's been waiting?

Comment: The first column is a Date, the number 5 you mention is an aggregate of count. Ther are 5 orders from first of october that are in waiting_for status. I want to highlight using multiple column conditions

Comment: Right. I still don't see how these rules apply. For example, 3 2021-10-04. The 9 in the Shipped column is not highlighted. It is more than 0 and 2021-10-04 was more than 29 days ago. Why is it not styled?

Comment: Sorry was 32, 34 and 36, I've just edited my question